# The Memory has been Increasing in WKWebView

Tags: ios, memory-management, xcode7.2, ios9.2.1

In my app, I load the interactive meeting URL on wkWebView, but I've noticed that the allocated memory has been gradually increasing.
When the app starts, memory is around 22 MB, but memory increases by the second.

How can I stop my memory from gradually increasing over time?

Comment: PLEASE HELP ANY BODY..

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/LaunchingInstruments.html

Try running your app in Instruments with the Leaks or Allocations filter to see what is causing your issues. Hopefully, that will lead you to the source of your memory leak(s).

Comment: Are you sure ? we can see allocations of Wkwebview in Instruments

Comment: What do you mean?